# Complex Regex optional search with multiple returned objects

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace

I'm trying to get the below to search with certain conditions.
There will always be the file name given, the others are optional.

`[[File:HumanMaleDiagram.png|right|300px|thumb|A diagram of a male human.]]`

The second item can be [left, right, center] or optional, the size is optional (either px or %), thumb is optional, the alt text at the end is optional.

I've used:

`var imageFinder = /\|\s*\[\[File\:([\w\-\_\. ]+)\|*(?=[right|left|center]*)\|*(?=[\w]*px)\|*(?=[thumb]*)\|*(?=[\w\.\s]*)\]\]/gi`

To return $1...$5

So I've used look-ahead's "?=" and "*" on the pipes but its not finding it.

Been using Regex in anger for the last few days only. All my others work (they're smaller than this) but some assistance would be gratefully received.

Doing this in JavaScript.

Thank you to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick snippet using [`exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), destructuring the results, and returning an object with a value of `undefined` for any capturing groups that are missing.

I wasn't sure if the pipes were permanent even if the string between was absent.

```js
const regex = /(?:File:([\w\s-]+\.\w{3,4}))\|(right|left|center)?\|(\d+(?:px|%))?\|(thumb)?\|(.*[^\]])?/i

const parse = (str) => {
  const [_, file, align, width, thumb, desc] = regex.exec(str);
  return { file, align, width, thumb, desc };
}

const
  str1 = '[[File:HumanMaleDiagram.png|right|300px|thumb|A diagram of a male human.]]',
  str2 = '[[File:Human_23.mp4|left|300%||A diagram of a male human.]]',
  str3 = '[[File:HumanMDiagram.jpeg||300%||A diagram of a human, male.]]';

console.log(parse(str1));
console.log(parse(str2));
console.log(parse(str3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

**String manipulation**

Given that your string is delimited with `|` characters you could forgo the regex and use standard string manipulation.

- Trim off the leading and trailing `[[` and `]]`

```
str = str.replace(/(?:^\[\[)|(?:\]\]$)/g, '')
```

- Split the result at the `|` characters.

```
str.split('|')
```

```js
const parse = (str) => {
  str = str.replace(/(?:^\[\[)|(?:\]\]$)/g, '');
  return str.split('|');
}

const
  str1 = '[[File:HumanMaleDiagram.png|right|300px|thumb|A diagram of a male human.]]',
  str2 = '[[File:Human_23.mp4|left|300%||A diagram of a male human.]]',
  str3 = '[[File:HumanMDiagram.jpeg||300%||A diagram of a human, male.]]';

console.log(parse(str1));
console.log(parse(str2));
console.log(parse(str3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make every part optional, so you don't need to use lookahead.

I recommend using [named capturing groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges#Using_named_groups) (but it's not required).

```
\[\[File:[^|]+(?:\|(?<align>left|right|center))?(?:\|(?<size>\d+(?:px|%)))?(?:\|(?<thumb>thumb))?(?:\|(?<alt>[^|]+))?\]\]
```

### [See this at work on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DAKK1R/1)